# java android socket connection

Tags: java, android, sockets, connection

I have a socket connection problem, I'm trying to connect my android phone with arduino board, and board is ok It's server with fixed Ip address and port number, I'm trying to send a string from android and it simply won't do, if anyone can see a mistake in my code or maybe a way to check if it even enters a thread as it should any help would be aprichiated

this is a code in main activity

```
 chcklighKitc = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chcklighKitc);
    chcklighKitc.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){


public void onClick(View v) {


    if (chcklighKitc.isChecked()) {
        Thread threadClient= new Thread(new ClientThread());
        threadClient.start();
        Toast.makeText(AndroidKitchenLightActivity.this,
           "Socket is send!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

And this is a code in ClientThread

```
public void run() {
    String serverIpAddr= "161.53.168.112";
    Socket socket;
    final int serverPort = 8888;



    String str="1";
    try {
        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddr);
        socket = new Socket(serverAddr, serverPort);

         PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
                                        // where you issue the commands
                                           out.println(str);
                                           out.flush();

      } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
         e1.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e1) {
         e1.printStackTrace();
      } catch (Exception e){
          Log.e("ClientActivity", "S: Error", e);
      }
```

Comment: What happens exactly? Which bit doesn't work?

Comment: Well arduino supposed just to turn on the light, but it doesn't do anything, so I'm not sure if it never starts a ClientThread, I added permision to manifest file , for internet maybe I need to add some other permission? Arduino never receves client request, so I believe it's android problem.

Comment: Add some logging to ClientThread to see if it starts.

Comment: @djedjica : which is exception is thrown? Can you tell that from the log file?

Comment: Sorry but now I have problem with logging, Unable to open log device catche you as soon as I handle this

Comment: All logs before line      socket = new Socket(serverAddr, serverPort);
  are writen as they supposed to, so everything apears fine but after nothing and I seem to not cought any exceptions because none of the logs in that section are writen out either :(